Why do I get WFM modualtion instead of AM in Colpitts generator?
Why do I get WFM modulation in simple AM modulators built on Colpitts generator?
When I did on 25 Mhz Xtal, it works perfectly fine, creating AM, instead of WFM.
The WFM modulation has very good sound quality when investigating by SDR and I think it's similar to the FM broadcast modulation.
Whether  I make the AM modulator on Colpitts generator, by diode modulator or by connecting modulating signal to the emitter leg, or by connecting the modulating signal to the base of NPN transistor and powering the whole circuit by that transistor, I still get something that looks like this:  The Colpitts oscillator I tested this on: 
So what can I do to make an AM modulator work? Based on an LC generator, instead of quartz, preferably on the diode modulator, 'cause I think it gives the best AM from all simple methods.

Have you a simulated waveform at output ?

Show us the picture of the resonator built with C4, C5 and L1, and the entire oscillator circuit as-built. The performance of this circuit depends quite a lot on how it's built and what the components are.


I get WFM modulation in simple am modulators built on Colpitts generator, but when I did on 25Mhz xtal, it works perfectly fine, creating AM.


The crystal has a very high Q and cannot be easily retuned to another frequency.

The LC resonator has a low Q and modulating the oscillator changes the load and source impedance on the resonator, and causes a frequency shift.


AM modulation of a Colpitts needs a different circuit, or a very high-Q resonator that will keep the frequency stable in spite of the changing impedances.
A good first step would be to keep the oscillator running from a constant current source (e.g. using a LDO to regulate the supply voltage), buffer the oscillator output, then AM-modulate that using just about any suitable circuit. A two-gate mosfet will do that job OK.
It may well be that your LC resonator has a low Q. Try to model it including various parasitic parameters of the real components you are using. You'll want to measure the self-resonance frequency of C4, C5 and L1 individually, as well as their Q at resonance. Then create a model of each of those components that has the same self-resonance and self-resonant Q. Then connect those models into a resonator, and model that using SPICE. You'll find that the modulation in SPICE will look just as wideband as the modulation in the real circuit.
At the very least, measure the series resistance of the inductor L1, and add that to the model. Also measure the series inductance of C4 and C5 and add those to the model. This will bring you a long way towards having a resonator with Q at least in the same order of magnitude as the real Q in-circuit. As long as the self-resonant frequencies of the capaciutors and the inductor are far above 30MHz.
If anything, you can probably wind an inductor with a shield between its two halves that will have about as much self-capacitance as the capacitors you have added in parallel to L1. The shield then connects to ground. Such an inductor will self-resonate roughly at the frequency you want, and will have quite a high Q due to very tight coupling of capacitance and inductance.

Thank you very much for your answer, i think your right, and the Q factor and impedance might be the issue. I have soldered that circuit on universal pcb from aliexpress and used 1 uH choke and 2 33pF capacitors. I think buffering the output of the oscillator would be the best solution.
